# Covering React-Redux Connect() using Flowtype

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype, static-analysis

I have the following code:

```
const mapStateToFilterProps = (state:DataExplorerState, props) => ({ loading: state.loading, filters: state.filters });

const actionCreators: ActionCreators<string, Action> = { updateLoadState, updateFilters, updateChartData};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)

// TODO: Fix typing issue
export const FilterBoxConnect = connect(
    mapStateToFilterProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps
)(FilterBox)
```

The code below the "TODO" says it is uncovered. How can I cover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may have been fixed. I don't know, I didn't test it but the maintainers alleged that that was the case: [Exhibit A](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6681), [Exhibit B](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/2553)

Comment: I have since tested it and it seemed to work fine. I promptly migrated to TypeScript and encourage everyone to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was uncovered because `connect` was not required to be explicitly annotated before 0.85. After 0.85, Flow will [ask for required annotations](https://medium.com/flow-type/asking-for-required-annotations-64d4f9c1edf8). Basically, if we do not explicitly annotate the connected components at export, Flow will report "implicitly instantiated" errors:

```sh
Missing type annotation for OP. OP is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly
instantiated at call of connect [2].
```

Also, we are now able to explicitly annotate `connect` by providing type parameters.

```
import * as React from 'react'

type OwnProps = {|
  passthrough: string,
  forMapStateToProps: string
|}

type Props = {|
  ...OwnProps,
  fromMapStateToProps: string,
  dispatch1: () => void
|}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div onClick={props.dispatch1}>
    {props.passthrough}
    {props.fromMapStateToProps}
  </div>
)

export default connect<Props, OwnProps, _, _, _, _>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent)
```

I have a more detailed guide [here](https://gist.github.com/wgao19/dfec19df95230949c610d2cadf4a40d5).